# After digit grouping conversions of numbers (hex,oct,bin,dec) not working

Tags: c#

i am working with scientific calculator in c#.net   .. after digit grouping , operations are not working .. ie. cant do conversions(decimal,octal,binary,hexagonal) ..
how can i solve it ?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSum.Text))
                    {
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                        int valueBefore = Int32.Parse(txtSum.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                        txtSum.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N0}", valueBefore);
                        txtSum.Select(txtSum.Text.Length, 0);
                    }
```

this is my code for digit grouping.. i want to convert decimal to hex, but after digit grouping its not converting dec to hex..

my conversion code is :

```
  long decValue = Convert.ToInt64(txtSum.Text);

                            string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X").ToUpper();
                            txtSum.Text = hexValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share relevant code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: In your first codeblock you are explicitly using "AllowThousands", you don't have that in the second block. Also you may need to use the culture also when parsing/converting.

Comment: Try and debug your code: what are the values of `txtSum.Text` and `decValue` (after your Convert in the second block)? Any error messages?

Comment: No error message.. But its not working..  and i am a starter in c#.net.